# Can an Android app be hacked to any effect?

Tags: android, web-services, security

Does anyone know if an app can be hacked to manipulate anything else beside the actual app or the host phone itself?  A web service server perhaps?  Is that even possible?  So the real question is, if an app is hacked, can the information it might possess or has access to be used for negative purposes?

(I'm looking to secure an app, not hack anyone.)  :)

Comment: If the question you are asking is: can a web service trust a client if the client is an Android app? the answer is no...  but that's really the same as with any client.

Comment: Please define "hacked" in this context.

Answer (score 2):

Web services are always vulnerable to being hacked.  This is why you use a secure connection such as SSL to transfer any sensitive information.

As far as directly hacking Android applications, I imagine a hacker would have to do something along the lines of decompiling an application to assembly, much as they do for traditional applications.

Any kind of storage on the device in non-compiled format (some XML, text files, preferences) is more vulnerable to being hacked than natively compiled .apk's.

Comment: Just for the record, there are some excellent disassemblers/decompilers for dalvik byte code.  It's not identical to the original source, but you can definitely tell what's going on.

Comment: It is compiled from Java and it's bytecode, so it typically is easier to figure out than say, compiled C code :)  Plus it's open source.

Comment: @Pheonixblad9 bingo! (btw I was agreeing with you...not sure if that was clear ;-) )

Answer (score 1):

I think everything is hackable...
It is quite easy to get access to all your application's data on a rooted device. Things like your database or your private files are accessible on a rooted device.